# Problem in using AWK in TCL expect

Tags: linux, awk, scripting, tcl

i am getting problem in using AWK command in TCK/TK
unix command:

```
var=`awk -v var1="^$line" -F "|" '$1~var1{print $1 }' sort-address-name-ip.txt | awk -v var2="$line$" '$0~var2'`
```

and i used as:

```
set var5 [exec /usr/bin/awk -v var1={^$line} -F {|} {$1~var1{print $1 }} sort-address-name-ip.txt | /usr/bin/awk  -v var2={$line$} {$0~var2}]
```

my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set file [ open /home/gcngov/script/practice/tcl/policy-unique_single_line-src-dst-ip.txt]
while {[gets $file line] != -1} {
        puts $line
        set file1 [open /home/gcngov/script/practice/tcl/sort-address-name-ip.txt]
        set var5 [exec /usr/bin/awk -v var1={^$line} -F {|} {$1~var1{print $1 }} sort-address-name-ip.txt | /usr/bin/awk  -v var2={$line$} {$0~var2}]
        puts $var5
}       

close $file
```

output:

```
~/script/practice/tcl$ expect -d while-file.sh 
expect version 5.45
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = while-file.sh  
set argc 0
set argv0 "while-file.sh"
set argv ""
executing commands from command file while-file.sh
10.13.210.212 
missing close-bracket
    while executing
"set var5 ["
    ("while" body line 5)
    invoked from within
"while {[gets $file line] != -1} {
        puts $line
        #set var [exec /usr/bin/awk -v var1="^$line" -F "|" $1~var1{print $1 } sort-address-name-ip.txt | awk..."
    (file "while-file.sh" line 3)
```

Comment: despite the @msp9011 edit, this still makes no sense. can the OP please fix the question?

Comment: At least fix the missing `]` at the end of the line starting `set var5`.

Comment: I highly recommend using perl and perl's `Expect.pm` module instead of expect+sh+awk.  All of the features of perl (a superset of awk and sed and sh and lots more) plus expect.  in one scripting language, No need to shell out to an external program or mess around with argument quoting.

Comment: You have an extra `exec` in there. That should look like `set var5 [exec awk ... | awk ...]` ie no `exec` after the pipe `|`. You should check the `exec(3tcl)` manpage. Also, all that could be done in `tcl` -- no need for external commands.

Comment: I've edited the missing bracket into your Q and removed the extra `exec` -- please try again and then revert my changes.

Comment: Please give an example of the input file and an example of what the output would look like. Maybe that will help me to understand what this is trying to do. As it is, I don't see why you need TCL at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Tcl, braces are like the shell's single quotes: no variable substitution is performed. You need to change

```
var1={^$line}
# to
var1="^$line"
```

and similarly for the 2nd awk.

However, I don't see why you're using 2 awks in a pipeline: it looks like you want to find the IPs from `policy-unique_single_line-src-dst-ip.txt` that appear in column 1 of pipe-delimited `sort-address-name-ip.txt` :

```
set ips [exec cut {-d|} -f1 sort-address-name-ip.txt | grep -Fxf policy-unique_single_line-src-dst-ip.txt]
```

Comment: Actually i am trying to get exact match from one file result to another with multiple  awk command to find exact value and then do some task.
eg. one awk with ^$line and another awk with $line\$